# How do I make GlideApp Compatible with androidx?

Tags: android-studio, androidx

I recently migrated my app from AppCompat to Androidx but now I'm facing a serious issue with GlideApp. Whenever I try building the project, it shows compilation failed.

I tried changing the following import statements,

```
import android.support.annotation.CheckResult;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
```

in the build folder to:

```
import androidx.annotation.CheckResult;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
```

But whenever I rebuild it just regenerates the former import statement and returns the following errors:

> error: package android.support.annotation does not exist   error:
>   cannot find symbol class NonNull

Comment: banned on all search engines? https://github.com/yuyakaido/CardStackView/pull/254

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found the fix by adding `annotationProcessor 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'` to my dependencies in app build.gradle and was able to build the project with no errors.

Got the solution from here: https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/3080#issuecomment-426331231